# Displaying an image over another image

Tags: laravel, carousel

I have a carousel showing images. Some of them are thumbs of youtube video in that case i want an image of a play button to be displayed over the thumb image to show that it is a video not a simple image.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
            @foreach($realisation->images as $key => $img)
                @if($img->type == 'image')
                <div class="item {{ $key == 0 ? 'active': '' }}"> 
                    @if(File::exists($img->image))
                        <img src="{{asset($img->image)}}" class="image" alt="realisation{{$img->id}}"/> 
                    @endif
                </div>
                @else
                <div class="item {{ $key == 0 ? 'active': '' }}"> 
                    <a href="{{$img->video}}"  data-lity>
                        <img src="{{ LaravelVideoEmbed::getYoutubeThumbnail($img->video) }}" class="image" alt="realisation{{$img->id}}">
                        <img src="{{asset('img/icon-14-orange.png')}}"  alt="">
                    </a>  
                </div>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

Comment: Ok what's your question?

Comment: how can i show the the second image icon-14-orange on the first one (the thumb of the video)

Comment: You would css to position the element. Since its over lapping it would be an absolute position .

Comment: Here look at this package: https://github.com/lakshmaji/Thumbnail

Comment: thank you the position:abosulte made it easier to do sorry if my question was a little bit dumb

Comment: Heh it's all good everyone starts with the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code, add class for play image `class="playOverlay"`:

```
    .....
    @else
       <div class="item {{ $key == 0 ? 'active': '' }}"> 
          <a href="{{$img->video}}"  data-lity>
              <img src="{{ LaravelVideoEmbed::getYoutubeThumbnail($img->video) }}" class="image" alt="realisation{{$img->id}}">
              <img class="playOverlay" src="{{asset('img/icon-14-orange.png')}}"  alt="">
         </a>  
      </div>
  @endif
    .....
```

css:

```
.item{position:relative}
img.playOverlay{
   position:absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```